# Edit existing html with zen coding snippet

Tags: html, emmet

Once I have expanded my zencoding snippet into HTML by pressing {tab}, how do I collapse that html back to a zencoding snippet in order to make changes to the zencoding expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Ctrl-Z (undo) is the way to do this.